# optimizing RapidFuzz for a list with large number of elements (e.g. 200,000)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzywuzzy, rapidfuzz

I would like to run this piece of rapidfuzz code mentioned in this post on a list with 200,000 elements. I am wondering what's the best way to optimize this for a faster run on GPU?

[Find fuzzy match string in a list with matching string value and their count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099425/find-fuzzy-match-string-in-a-list-with-matching-string-value-and-their-count/61102196#61102196)

```
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import fuzz

elements = ['vikash', 'vikas', 'Vinod', 'Vikky', 'Akash', 'Vinodh', 'Sachin', 'Salman', 'Ajay', 'Suchin', 'Akash', 'vikahs']

results = [[name, [], 0] for name in elements]

for (i, element) in enumerate(elements):
    for (j, choice) in enumerate(elements[i+1:]):
        if fuzz.ratio(element, choice, score_cutoff=90):
            results[i][2] += 1
            results[i][1].append(choice)
            results[j+i+1][2] += 1
            results[j+i+1][1].append(element)

data = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['name', 'duplicates', 'duplicate_count'])
```

Expected Output -

```
name        duplicates  duplicate_count
0   vikash           [vikas]                1
1    vikas  [vikash, vikahs]                2
2    Vinod          [Vinodh]                1
3    Vikky                []                0
4    Akash           [Akash]                1
5   Vinodh           [Vinod]                1
6   Sachin                []                0
7   Salman                []                0
8     Ajay                []                0
9   Suchin                []                0
10   Akash           [Akash]                1
11  vikahs           [vikas]                1
```

Comment: GPU are not great for string operation with a variable size because the operation is not SIMT-friendly. One may find a way to speed up a bit the operation but the code will be very complex and low-level. If you really want to do that on a GPU, then using existing packages is the only sane option (not sure there is an efficient one because of the performance issue). Using a native language for such an operation should give you a significant speed up (starting from the vectorization and the parallelization of the operation not to mention the string-based optimization that can be applied).

Comment: Can you give us a sample expected out

Comment: Edited the post to include the expected output @Vishnudev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rapidfuzz` library has a function for speedup which takes the parallel processing power of CPU to quicken the process.

The `workers` argument enables parallel processing. With the value `workers=-1`, you will be using all the cores available.

```
from rapidfuzz.process import cdist

# Calculate distance between all the names
sa = cdist(elements, elements, score_cutoff=90, workers=-1)

duplicates_list = []

for distances in sa:
    # Get indices of duplicates
    indices = np.argwhere(~np.isin(distances, [100, 0])).flatten()
    # Get names from indices
    names = list(map(elements.__getitem__, indices))
    duplicates_list.append(names)

# Create dataframe using the data
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': elements, 'duplicates': duplicates_list})
df['duplicate_count'] = df.duplicates.str.len()
```

Output

```
      name        duplicates  duplicate_count
0   vikash           [vikas]                1
1    vikas  [vikash, vikahs]                2
2    Vinod          [Vinodh]                1
3    Vikky                []                0
4    Akash                []                0
5   Vinodh           [Vinod]                1
6   Sachin                []                0
7   Salman                []                0
8     Ajay                []                0
9   Suchin                []                0
10   Akash                []                0
11  vikahs           [vikas]                1
```